# $.ajaxSetUp Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got $.ajaxSetUp() , In which I have defined headers .  When ever an ajax request is made I'm expecting ajax to pass these headers defined in $.ajaxSetUp  along with that request . But its not happening .

For example : I got two buttons, I'm expecting headers will be sent along with these two events . But it is not happening . How Can I send headers along with these requests.

```
 function ajaxSetUp() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        headers: { "CustomHeader": "Value1" },
    });
}

$('#btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'HOME/POSTSAMPLEACTION',
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: "test" },
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        //headers: {
        //    'VerificationToken': forgeryId
        //},
        success: function (returnVal) {
            alert(returnVal);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("failed");
        },
    });
});


$('#btn1').click(function () {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'HOME/ADDACTION',
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: "test" },
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    //headers: {
    //    'VerificationToken': forgeryId
    //},
    success: function (returnVal) {
        alert(returnVal);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("failed");
    },
   });
```

});

```
     [AjaxValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult PostSampleAction(string name)
    {
        return this.Json("Post Passed Validation -" + name);
    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace AntiForgerySample
 {
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AjaxValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
   public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) // if it is ajax request.
            {
                this.ValidateRequestHeader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request); // run the validation.
            }
            else
            {
                AntiForgery.Validate();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
        {
            throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Anti forgery token not found");
        }
    }

 private void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        string cookieToken = string.Empty;
        string formToken = string.Empty;
        string customHeader = string.Empty;
        string tokenValue = request.Headers["VerificationToken"]; // read the header key and validate the tokens.
        customHeader = request.Headers["CustomHeader"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
        {
            string[] tokens = tokenValue.Split(',');
            if (tokens.Length == 2)
            {
                cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
            }
        }

        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken); // this validates the request    token.
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please reread your description and re write it so it is understandable. It is completely ambiguous. You say it works on every request but you want it dynamic on every request. No idea what the difference is.

Comment: In order to answer this question, you must explain how your script(s) are organized. Is there only one script file containing both jQuery and your custom script, or two script files - jQuery and your custom script and so on? We need to know how they are loaded in the browser.

Comment: I got Jquery script first and then my Custom script file

Comment: Even with the edit it is still not clear what you are trying to do. `$.ajaxSetup` is intended to be used once globally. please be more specific on what exactly you need to do. I think you are wanting a factory method for your ajax calls

Comment: @user3270152 If possible , can post "Jquery script first" and "Custom script file" at OP ? , describe expected results of both ? Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @ guest271314 : I will go through the link , thank you . I have edited my question Can you please check once?

Comment: What method is used to determine if the headers _are_ , or, _are not_ posted to url ? How are `headers` processed at `url` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// default options
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    headers: { "CustomHeader": "Value1" },
    url: 'HOME/POSTSAMPLEACTION',
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: "test" },
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (returnVal) {
        alert(returnVal);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("failed");
    }
});

$('#btn').click(function () {
  // pass custom options here , if required , 
  // to override default options at `$.ajaxSetup`
  $.ajax();
});
```

Comment: @user3270152 `is not working` doesn't explain anything and is a worthless technical description...you really need a better explanation of what you are trying to acheive

Comment: @user3270152 Try http://jsfiddle.net/wdxtv802/ . Perhaps , edit piece to include all relevant `html` , `js` ; repost edited jsfiddle at original post ?

Comment: @user3270152 _"When ever an ajax request is made I'm expecting ajax to pass these headers defined in $.ajaxSetUp along with that request . But its not happening ."_ . The `headers` should be passed at each call of `$.ajax()` , see console and string version of headers appended to document after each `click` http://jsfiddle.net/wdxtv802/1/ ; same piece as posted above and original jsfiddle.

Comment: @guest271314 :I'm trying to put Headers in ajaxSetUp() because that is the only thing common ,remaining parameters keeps on changing. Headers are not posted back if i'm doing so

Comment: Not certain about _"Headers are not posted back"_ ? What effect is expected by posting `headers` to `url` ? What is expected response ? The posted `headers` are available at `this.headers` within `$.ajax` `then` callback

Comment: When I'm Checking it is saying undefined

Comment: Not certain about `AjaxValidateAntiForgeryToken` piece ? Perhaps another SO viewer can help there . `$.ajaxSetup()` appear to be passing `headers` from results at http://jsfiddle.net/wdxtv802/1/ , not sure where viewing `undefined` ?